# Nuxt Hanging during generate script

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, contentful

When I try to run the generate script with nuxt my node process ends up hanging.

Nuxt goes through the generate step, but hangs with my console saying "Generate errors summary" and then nothing.

```
nuxt:render Rendering url / +5s
nuxt: Call generate:done hooks (1) +13ms
nuxt:generate HTML Files generated in 46.1s +14ms

Generate errors summary:
```

Has anyone run into this before?

Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "contentful": "^6.1.1",
    "contentful-management": "^5.1.4",
    "nuxt": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-markdown": "^2.2.4"
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "eslint": "^3.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1"
 }
```

Comment: It's difficult to assist you without knowing nuxt version or seeing the code

Comment: added version info, don't really know where the problem is so not sure what is the best code snippet to provide.  Trying to mimic the contentful blog-in-5-minutes.

Comment: dev dep look dated, also 46.1s to build is a long time, try a fresh install/project and work backwards from there.

Comment: Looks like the problem was in my css.  I included a LOT of css and removing it and nuxt zips right on through. Next problem is how to fix that, but at least I'm past this issue. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't have a CSS loader, added one and everything works.

From the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css/)

```
Nuxt.js will automatically guess the file type by it's extension and use the 
appropriate pre-processor loader for webpack. You will still need to install 
the required loader if you need to use them.
```